# Winless NameError despite variables being imported

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm using Notepad++ and in my settings I have `UTF-8 without BOM` checked. But still when Winless auto-compiles my .less files it returns a `NameError: variable @background is undefined ...`.

I've read that Notepad++ should be fine when working with .less files and imports, but somehow it's still causing trouble. If Notepad++ is the problem, that is.

Anybody an idea what could be the problem?

**index.less**

```
@import: "variables.less";
@import: "mixins.less";

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
    color: #333;
    background: @background;
}

b { font-weight: bold }
i { font-style: italic }
u { text-decoration: underline }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove colons after the `@import` rule:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake of mine to make! Thanks a lot.